# Обновление значения TextBox при нажатии кнопки "Enter"

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

На View имеется textbox, сейчас в коде значение обновляется при каждом изменении текста.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding IntValues}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <GroupBox Header="{Binding Name}">
                <StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="Текущее значение"
                                   Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}"/>
                        <TextBlock Margin="5 0 0 0"
                                   Text="{Binding PresentValue}"
                                   Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="Новое значение"
                                   Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}"/>
                        <TextBox Margin="15 2.5 0 2.5"
                                 Height="15"
                                 Width="45"
                                 Text="{Binding NewValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                 />
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </GroupBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Вот свойство из ViewModel(оно не допилено):

```
public int NewValue
{
    get => _newValue;
    set
    {
        _newValue = value;
        //для тестирования обновления.
        PresentValue = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(PresentValue));
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(NewValue));
        //Добавить отправку команды на запись.
    }
}
```

Необходимо реализовать изменение только при нажатии кнопки "Enter".
Сейчас в голову приходит только создание отдельной команды, которая будет выполняться по нажатию кнопки.
Можно ли это реализовать другим способом? Есть ли какие-то свойства для реализации подобного?

Comment: @DenisBubnov: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Нет. Заводите отдельную команду.

Comment: @Андрей: спасибо, тогда вопрос считаю закрытым.
Потом добавлю свою реализацию для будущих поколений.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, необходимо, чтобы текст из `TextBox`'а «проваливался» в VM при нажатии Enter. Это как раз подходящее применение для attached behavior. Добавляем ссылку на `System.Windows.Interactivity` и пишем:

```
class UpdateBindingOnEnterBehavior : Behavior<TextBox>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.KeyDown += OnKeyDown;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.KeyDown -= OnKeyDown;
        base.OnDetaching();
    }

    static void OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter && sender is TextBox tb)
            tb.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty)?.UpdateSource();
    }
}
```

Пользуемся в коде так:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding T}"
         xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <local:UpdateBindingOnEnterBehavior/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBox>
```

`UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` не применяем. Если обновления VM при потере фокуса не нужно, можно использовать `UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit` (но тогда нужно обновить VM и при закрытии окна).

(Определение `xmlns:i`, наверное, стоит перенести на уровень окна.)

Comment: Ну надо дополнить, что по потере фокуса обновление источника привязки также останется. Подойдет ли это автору - другой вопрос...

Comment: @Андрей: Ну это да. Или можно указать `UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit`.

Comment: Точно, про `Explicit` забыл!